# How to get data json with https not http in php codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

the result of json data from url with https is messy and like error string character used file_get content like in this code below

```
<?php

// header('Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
// header("Content-Type: text/html");

$url = "https://sirup.lkpp.go.id/sirup/servicecdn/paketpenyediapersatkertampil ?idSatker=95966&tahunAnggaran=2018";

// $url="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";
// $url="http://localhost/appTestBengkulu/restAPI/aksesdata/";

$get_url = file_get_contents($url);
$datajson = json_decode($get_url);
var_dump($get_url);

// var_dump($datajson);

$data_array = array(
    'datalist' => $datajson
);

// var_dump($data_array);

$this->load->view('vdatajson', $data_array);
```

with:file_get content url
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tGYU4lwAHKQMs8bN5Z9ns-45c4IZEZe_

with postman :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-G_2LBT53vq-jyHWahBQyAdT203O86CY/view?usp=sharing

i used some suggest like content type utf8 or like that but the result is same
data can read like array data json for view

Comment: How are you printing the vdatajson in the view?

Comment: It might be a mistake when you posted your code, but there is space before `?idSatker` part in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues in there, first in the url there is space between `paketpenyediapersatkertampil` and  `?idSatker`, remove it.
Second, the data returned is gzip formatted, you can use `gzdecode` function to decompress it first before `json_decode` it :

```
<?php

// header('Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
// header("Content-Type: text/html");

$url = "https://sirup.lkpp.go.id/sirup/servicecdn/paketpenyediapersatkertampil?idSatker=95966&tahunAnggaran=2018";

// $url="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";
// $url="http://localhost/appTestBengkulu/restAPI/aksesdata/";

$get_url = file_get_contents($url);
$datajson = json_decode(gzdecode($get_url));
// var_dump($get_url);

// var_dump($datajson);

$data_array = array(
    'datalist' => $datajson
);

var_dump($data_array);

$this->load->view('vdatajson', $data_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

cURL works well

Here is a working snippet.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://sirup.lkpp.go.id/sirup/servicecdn/paketpenyediapersatkertampil?idSatker=95966&tahunAnggaran=2018",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```